# Count rows in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want count unique $hotel in SearchResult.   I new variable to pass in view.

Class:

```
 * 
     *
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Uts\HotelBundle\Repository\SearchResult")
     * @ORM\Table(name="search_result")
     */
    class SearchResult
    {
        ------
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SearchRequest")
         * @var
         */
        private $request;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hotel")
         * @var Hotel
         */
        private $hotel;
    ---
    }
```

Pass variable to view:

```
   $query2 = $repository->hotelsCount($searchId);
             //  var_dump($query2);
               $templateVars['count']=$query2;
            }
            return $this->render('UtsHotelBundle:Default:results.html.twig', $templateVars)
```

Function hotelsCount:

```
  public function hotelsCount($requestId){

     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('self');
    $qb->select('count DISTINCT(p.hotel)');
    $qb->from('HotelBundle:SearchResult','p')
        ->where('p.request_id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id',$requestId);
    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
```

Table searchResult:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do a more reusable query like

```
public function getHotelsByRequest($requestId){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('self');
    $qb
        ->where('self.request_id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id',$requestId);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Then in your controller

```
$hotels = $repository->getHotelsByRequest($searchId);
$templateVars['count']= count($hotels);
```